# Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

**Here is the code I'm trying to execute to encode the values of the first column of my data set using dummy values
**

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

# divide dataset to dependent variable(features) and independent variable(output)
X = dataset.iloc[: , :-1].values 
y = dataset.iloc[: ,3].values

# taking care of missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')

# apply the simpleImputer on the x from column[age to salary]
imputer = imputer.fit(X[: , 1:3 ])

# replace the missing data by the processed data 
X[: , 1:3 ] = imputer.transform(X[: , 1:3 ])


#  Encoding categorical data [country]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[: ,0])
# creates a binary column for each category
onehotencoder_X = OneHotEncoder(categories=['France','Germany','Spain'])
X_1 = onehotencoder_X.fit_transform(X[: ,0].reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
X = np.concatenate([X_1,X[: , 1:]],axis = 1)
```

```
            the data that i work on
```

[image: the data that i work on]

```
         i'm getting an error
```

[image: i'm getting an error]

Can anyone help me fix this?

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient way to encode categorical features is using pandas' facilities. I implement this as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['French', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Spain']})
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
df['categorical_feature'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['feature'])
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')# passing cat column (label encoded values of df)
enc_df = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(df[['categorical_feature']]).toarray(), columns=labelencoder.classes_)# merge with main df on key values
df = df.join(enc_df)
df
```

output:

```
   feature  categorical_feature  French  Germany  Spain
0   French                    0     1.0      0.0    0.0
1  Germany                    1     0.0      1.0    0.0
2  Germany                    1     0.0      1.0    0.0
3    Spain                    2     0.0      0.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**the Answer **

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
#label_encoder object
label_encoder_X = LabelEncoder()
#Encode labels in columns
X[ : , 0] = label_encoder_X.fit_transform(X[: , 0])

# creates a binary column for each category
onehot_encoder=OneHotEncoder(categories=[[ 0 , 1 , 2 ]])
onehot_encoder=onehot_encoder.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
X = np.concatenate([onehot_encoder,X[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

[After Run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqiWw.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).